# How to change a layout in same activity by clicking a Button?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Change a layout in same `Activity` when  click on play button then layout show pause `Button` at the same place in `Android Studio` music player app.
How it is possible? 
I'm a beginner so I don't know how to use method about it?
I cannot get an answer.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is there any error that you face?

Comment: i cannot understand which method is used thats why i ask.

Comment: Add your piece of code, which layout to be changed etc.. So that we can support in answering the question

Comment: can't you just change icon of play button, to pause button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand from your question that when your user taps `pause` button, you should hide `pause` button and show `play` button and vice-versa. This is relatively simple to achieve. Just create a layout with a linear layout with two buttons like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Play"
        android:padding="5dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPause"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Pause"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now set on click listner to both of the buttons and handle button visibility within that like this :

```
Button btnPlay = barcodeDialog.findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
Button btnPause = barcodeDialog.findViewById(R.id.btnPause);

btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        btnPlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);                    
    }
});


btnPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        btnPlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btnPause.setVisibility(View.GONE);                   
    }
});
```

This way you can handle the visibility of your `Play` and `Pause` buttons. Reply if you need more information.